# Use LINQ to SQL with new Visual Studio Project format?

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-project

Is there a way to make Visual Studio `LINQ to SQL tools` to work with new Visual Studio project format?

I do following 2 steps:

1. I create new class library and set `TargetFramework` as `net48` (or lower):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

2. I right click on the project (class library), `Add` -> `New Item...`, LINQ to SQL Classes (*.dbml extension).

At this point Visual Studio 2019 (latest, v16.4.2) just hangs (not responding - indefinitely).

Is there a way to make LINQ to SQL tools work with new project format?

*P.S. `LINQ to SQL tools` are correctly installed (Installer -> Individual components)*